# SQL Return row from MAX() function

Tags: sql, mariadb

My first foray into SQL and I'm having some difficulty applying the MAX() function.

If I run the following, I receive the correct returned value:

```
SELECT MAX(count) 
FROM readings
```

However, when I try to also return fields related to that value, I get an incorrect return. Running the following returns the correct 'count' value but an incorrect 'location' value

```
SELECT MAX(count), location 
FROM readings
```

What I expected from the above, are results the same as from:

```
SELECT count, location 
FROM readings
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Could you please advise if it is possible to achieve this using the `MAX()` function or if I have just misunderstood what `MAX` actually does!

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah, apologies. Inexperience showing there! Its MariaDB

Comment: Added the `mariadb` tag to make this clear to everyone reading your question !

Comment: Thanks Marc. Patience appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database system are you using? `MAX` is an [aggregation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) that should be operating across the entire table, while selecting a single value (like `location` in your query) is operating only on a single row. In most databases, if you want to select another column, you must specify that column in a `GROUP BY` clause or also wrap it in a similar aggregation function.

To get the value of `location` in the same row, you typically should use a subselect, like this:

```sql
SELECT count, location
FROM readings
WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM readings);
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee a single result, though; there could be several rows that match the maximum `count` value!

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! I had been trying something similar earlier but abandoned it. I was running:

```SELECT count, location  
FROM readings  
WHERE year=2015 AND count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM readings);```

I believe this was failing because it was attempting to find the maximum count value within 2015 and then returned blank because the actual max was not in that year.

Is there a way to apply MAX to work within a specific condition like i.e. 2015 or will MAX always run on the entire table?

Comment: You can specify a `WHERE` clause with the `MAX` function, and the `MAX` will apply to the limited set implied by the where clause. Your SQL there looks fine, but the subselect just needs to have a `WHERE` clause added to it. (You'd need to keep the outer `WHERE` as well, so that you don't get things from other years that happen to match.)

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you very much asthasr!